# Can not able to run single file in cypress

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, cypress, node-modules

I have a 5 .js file under the integration folder and want to run single .js file in cypress. but error thrown like:

> The following validation error was thrown by your plugins file
> (`C:\Users\admin\LegrandRX\cypress\plugins\index.js`). Error: The
> `before:run` event requires the experimentalRunEvents flag to be
> enabled. To enable it, set `"experimentalRunEvents": true` in your cypress.json

I have set `script: { "cy:run": "cypress run"}`
and I have also tried `"experimentalRunEvents": true` in cypress.json according to error but nothing to successed

Cypress.json file added from comment:

```js
{
  "reporter": "cypress-mochawesome-reporter",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "reportDir": "cypress/reports",
    "charts": true,
    "overwrite": false,
    "html": false,
    "json": true,
    "reportPageTitle": "My Test Suite",
    "embeddedScreenshots": true,
    "inlineAssets": true,
    "experimentalRunEvents": true
  },
  "video": false
}
```

Comment: can you post your `cypress.json` file?

Comment: Please Check cypress.json file here`{
    "reporter": "cypress-mochawesome-reporter",
    "reporterOptions": {
    "reportDir": "cypress/reports",
    "charts": true,
    "overwrite": false,
    "html": false,
    "json": true,
    "reportPageTitle": "My Test Suite",
    "embeddedScreenshots": true,
    "inlineAssets": true,
    "experimentalRunEvents":true
  },
    "video":false
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `"experimentalRunEvents":true` outside the `reporterOptions`

```js
{
  "reporter": "cypress-mochawesome-reporter",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "reportDir": "cypress/reports",
    "charts": true,
    "overwrite": false,
    "html": false,
    "json": true,
    "reportPageTitle": "My Test Suite",
    "embeddedScreenshots": true,
    "inlineAssets": true
  },
  "experimentalRunEvents": true,
  "video": false
}
```

To run a single spec file you can use the command:

```js
cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/examples/actions.spec.js"
```